# How can I collapse div and open tab with bootstrap or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want when I click link and smoot-scrool to down then `collapse` `div` and open `tab` with `Javascript`.

This code is scrolled

```
 <a data-scroll href="#smootScrool" onclick="callMyFunction('tab-1')"><h4 >Scrool, collapse and open tab authomatic</h4></a>
```

to here and with handle I can collapse and open tap, but I wan't do it authomatic with Javascript. How can I do it?

```
  <div class="panel-heading"><span id="smootScrool" "> Scrolled Here!</span>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse-9" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down control-icon"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-universal-access"> Qeydiyyatsız müraciət</i> 
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse-9" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 page-content ">
                <div class="hr1 margin-top"></div>
                <div class="tabs-section">
                    <!-- Nav Tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs center-block">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-question"></i>TAB 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>TAB 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>TAB 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-legal"></i>TAB 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panels -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <!-- Tab Content 1 -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-1">
                            <div class="row">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

1. Scrool to div (this working)
2. Authomatic collapse div (How can I do?)
3. Authomatic open tab (How can I do?)

Please suggestion best way and code example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the official bootstrap documentation about that, could be helpful or at least give you an better idea how to find a solution: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Also Jquery UI: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover

I hope that these links can be useful